# What does "have a shifty at" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> ‘Well, Molly, I'm pretty sure this is a boggart,’ said Sirius, peering through the keyhole, ‘but perhaps we ought to let Mad-Eye **have a shifty at** it before we let it out — knowing my mother, it could be something much worse.’
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't understand the phrase "have a shifty at". "Shifty" is actually an adjective word, but here it's used as a noun. I guess it probably means *to let Mad-Eye take a look at it with his shifty eyes*, but I don't know if it's a correct interpretation. How should we understand it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have found some slang there.

I haven't found a better source than this entry in a [Cockney Rhyming site](http://www.myenglishlanguage.com/linguistics-language-guide/idioms-and-slang/cockney-rhyming-slang/)

> The phrase **have a shifty at** is actually **have a shufty at**. This
>   comes from the Arabic word *shufti* which means **have you seen?** The
>   word was brought into the English language by British soldiers serving
>   in the Middle East and is used as a slang expression for **take a
>   look**.

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+shufti)

> **have a shufti**
>  To look at something briefly. ("Shufti" originated as a
>   military term.) Primarily heard in UK

I think that these explanations make sense with your text.

As you have already stated

> it probably means to let Mad-Eye **take a look**

but you can drop the last part about his shifty eyes